# How to track the API calls in Phalcon

Tags: php, api, phalcon

I need to track the APIs called from different users in Phalcon and insert user's IP address into a log file. How can I do this in Phalcon?

Comment: At least provide references to research you have already done and code that you have already tried. This is too broad.

Comment: Phalcon provides Logging class. Have you checked the docs? https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/logging.html But you have to write your own code to handle logging.

Answer (score 2):

Phalcon has a class specifically for logging, combining this with route events you can elegantly log the activity of users. In your controller (I reccomend using ControllerBase as it will log all instances of a user requesting a resource):

```
use Phalcon\Events\Event;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;
use Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File as FileAdapter;

class ControllerBase extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Executed after every found action is executed
     * Logs all requests to controllers
     *
     * @param \Phalcon\Events\Event $event
     * @param \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher $dispatcher
     * @return void
     */
    public function afterExecuteRoute(Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
        // Set up a logger instance
        $logger = new FileAdapter("app/logs/request.log");

        // Log the message
        $logger->info(sprintf("Client %s executed %s::%s on route %s", 
            $this->request->getClientAddress(),
            $dispatcher->getControllerName(),
            $dispatcher->getActionName(),
            $this->request->getURI()
        ));

        // Save the log 
        $logger->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnSk if this was the answer to your question, please accept it

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using MVC.

The better way to do this, is creating a ControllerBase, with extends all your controllers. Then you add a method called "onConstruct", to do whatever you want before all controllers be executed, like so:

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\Api\Controllers;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
use Phalcon\Http\Response;
use Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File;

class ControllerBase extends Controller {

    public function onConstruct(){
        // here is your code
    }

}
```

If you are using just one controller to handle all requests of your API, just add the onConstruct method in this controller, not need for extends.

Then in this method, you can do this to get the IP and save to a file:

```
public function onConstruct(){
    $ip_client = $this->request->getClientAddress(); // Here, you get the IP

    $logger = new \Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\File('../logs/requests.log', array('mode' => 'w'));
    $logger->error('['.date("H:i:s").']: '. " You are doing requests in my API: " . $ip_client);
    $logger->close();

}
```

I added this on the construct, but you can create a method just to do this, for saving logs in all actions in your application. There is a nice way to do this, creating a model or a helper class, with handle this logs:

```
$log = new \Logger();
$log->setMessage("You are doing some request in my API, funny");
$log->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use `dispatcher` and `beforeExecuteRoute`. Also you can create custom listener as a class for events in it. Also you can still get request(and ip, params, post, json etc from di container calling it in static way).

https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/dispatching.html